# PyQt4 : is there any signal related to scrollbar?

Tags: pyqt, scrollbar, pyqt4, signals-slots, qlistwidget

I plan to create a two listWidget and they have same amount of list.
So, when a listWidget scroll up and down, another one also travel it's list.
But, I can't find related signal.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to connect the `valueChanged` signals of one scrollbar to the `setValue` slot of the other scrollbar (and vice versa).

At first glance, this might seem dangerously recursive, but Qt seems to handle it without any problem, as this example shows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.listA = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.listB = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listA)
        layout.addWidget(self.listB)
        for index in range(100):
            self.listA.addItem('Sample text for Item %d' % index)
            self.listB.addItem('Sample text for Item %d' % index)
        self.listA.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.listB.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.listB.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.listA.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.listA.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.listB.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.listB.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.listA.verticalScrollBar().setValue)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. I can manage the listWidget well :)

Comment: My reputation point shows "11", so I can't vote up the answer. And I'm familiar with the system. So, I don't know the way improve my reputation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

[QListWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) inherits [QListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html), which inherits [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html), which...

Anyway you can see all QListWidget members clicking on [List of all members, including inherited members](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget-members.html), where you find [verticalScrollBar () const : QScrollBar *](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBar) method, which is inherited from QAbstractScrollArea.

You can connect to the `listWidget`'s vertical scrollbar [valueChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) signal:

```
listWidget.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(onScrollBarValueChanged)
```

Where `onScrollBarValueChanged` is the slot (signal handler).

Answer (score 0):

To track the scrollbar movement, you must reimplement the `scrollContentsBy()` virtual function. Take a look also to the `QAbstractSlider::actionTriggered()` signal and to the `sliderPosition` property